# bind non static templated member function in derived class

Tags: c++, function, templates, binding, class-hierarchy

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Plain {
   public:
    template <typename Type>
    void member_function(const Type& s) {
        std::cout << "Recived: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename Type>
class Templated : private Plain {
   public:
};

int main() {
    Plain b;
    b.member_function<int>(10); // done!
    Templated<int> d;
    // d.member_function();  /* how to achive this */

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to call the member function in `class Plain` by two method:

1. createing non-templated class and padding type while calling function

```
Plain p;
p.member_function<int>();
```

2. passing type while creating class and calling without template param

```
Templated<int> t;
t.member_function(); // achive this
```

I tried doing binding the function in derived class like

```
struct Plain{
    template<typename T>
    static void member_function(const T& s){std::cout << s << std::endl;}
}

template<typename T>
struct Templated : private Plain {
    std::function<void(const T&)> print = Templated::Plain::member_function;
}
```

and after that I was able to do

```
Templated t<std::string>;
t.print();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you want `d.member_function();` to do? I understand you want the `int` version of this template, but you are not passing it the needed argument. Also, the `print` version you showed doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't call a function template; it needs to be instantiated, and it can only be automatically instantiated if the compiler can deduce the template arguments. And you can't call a function that takes arguments without passing those arguments, so it's not clear why you're expecting to be able to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct Test {
    template <typename Type>
    void foo(const Type&) {
        std::cout << "I am just a foo..." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   private:
    Test* obj;

   public:
    Foo() : obj(new Test) {}
    std::function<void(const int&)> foo = std::bind(&Test::foo<T>, obj, _1);
    ~Foo() { delete obj; }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> me;
    me.foo(10);

    Test t;
    t.foo<int>(89);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

When you use private inheritance the methods in Plain are inaccessible to outside code, and you need to have something inside of Templated make the call to the method in Plain; you can do so, or alternatively you could use public inheritance and be able to hit it directly.

```
class Plain {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void print(const T & s) {
        std::cout << "Received: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Templated : private Plain {
public:
    void print(const T & s) {
        Plain::print<T>(s);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Alternative : public Plain {};

int main() {
    Templated<int> t;
    t.print(3); // This could work

    Alternative<int> a;
    a.print(4); // As could this

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this method work but what if I dont have access to source of Base class

Comment: @Dev-il such as when you have the declaration of plain and the method in a header (.h) file but the definition of the method is in a source (.cpp) file?

Comment: no I mean if the Base class is compiled or is in a lib. Something like that when i sont have source code.

Comment: If the base class was defined in a lib then you should have a header file that includes the declaration of the base class and the method; else I'm not sure how you'd inherit from it; often libraries will include the method body of templated methods in the header (such that you do in effect have the source), if they do not, then you can only invoke the templated method with the template parameters that they have explicitly instantiated in their library e.g. https://github.com/jjf28/Chkdraft/blob/master/MappingCoreLib/Scenario.cpp#L1120